# Does COVID-19 cause GI symptoms?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, symptoms

Some of the more common symptoms of COVID-19 are fever and cough. There has been [some evidence](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/2762997) of SARS-Cov-2 in feces. Do we have any further knowledge of the prevalence of GI symptoms among those with COVID-19?

Comment: Did you research any of the previous questions?

Comment: Answered https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/21751/3414

Comment: Didn't see that question in my search. Thank you!

Comment: @BryanKrause yes it does, thank you